# Laravel-Event: How to use Auth::user() in a Event?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-events

When I ask  if(Auth::user()->role == "xxxx") inside CandidateEvent displays "Trying to get property of non-object"

The problem is that component Auth::user() isn't working in my Event.

What is the correct way to use Auth within Events?

```
public function __construct()
{
    if(Auth::user()->role == "XXXX")
    {
        $candidate = count(Candidate::CountNewCandidate());
    }
    else
    {
        $candidate = count(Candidate::CountNewCandidateGroup());
    }
    $this->data = [ 'cCandidate' => $candidate ];        
}
```

Comment: An image of the code is not a good idea. Please think about reformatting your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. And now? (Is the event code)

Comment: Pass the user to the event in the data.

Comment: It works, thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no authenticated user `Auth::user()` will return `null`, so `Auth::user()->role` will raise the `Trying to get property of non-object`; Try to check if there is an authenticated user by using `Auth::check()` then you can check the role :

```
public function __construct()
{
    if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->role == "XXXX")
    {
        $candidate = count(Candidate::CountNewCandidate());
    }
    else
    {
        $candidate = count(Candidate::CountNewCandidateGroup());
    }
    $this->data = [ 'cCandidate' => $candidate ];        
}
```

Note: I used the helper function [`auth()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-auth).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: The problem is that component Auth::user() isn't working in my Event, and i'm already using "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth";

Comment: Try to use the helper `auth()` , `auth()->user()`  ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason Auth::user() is null in an event (particularly if it is queued), is because there is no user.  The authentication data is typically stored in a session and when your even is triggered there is no session variable therefore no session data.

In the past I have passed in the user in the event, then to authenticate the user within the event handler I would call:

```
\Auth::attempt(['email', $event->performedBy()->email]);
```

This was necessary because my application had many functions tightly coupled with Authentication (instead of a UserInterface).  Ideally I could have just passed in the user as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't import the namespace for the Auth facade. You have to add it in the declarations

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it passing the user to event, through data in the routes:

```
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['xxxx']], function () {
    event(new NameEvent($data));
    Route::auth();
});
```